# How to commit just one block in oracle forms 11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

I have a form than contains four blocks, and I want to commit the data in just one block before the others.

I tried Commit or commit_form, but it will try to save all the blocks.

Is there a way to validate just one block without flushing data from other blocks?

Comment: What exactly do you need to achieve? I mean from user point od view? Unfortunately there is no way to commit only one block. You can validate only one block. Can you tell us the use case?

Comment: The problem is that in some cases the user may insert data in a block_1 and then needs to insert data in block_2 to use it in the first one, si he go_block('block_2') before he finished the first block so I need just to commit the second one and after return to the first finish the insertion and then commit it.